# How to write the data but do not repeat the plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, plist

The following code has been correctly write plist, but no way to detect whether there is to write the same data.

How to do it does not already joined the data to repeat the join.

```
-(void)saveData{

    // Create the new dictionary that will be inserted into the plist.
    NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [nameDictionary setValue:wooname forKey:@"wooname"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woodata forKey:@"woodata"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woojclass forKey:@"woojclass"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woojtime forKey:@"woojtime"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woojpin forKey:@"woojpin"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woojsps forKey:@"woojsps"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:woojspall forKey:@"woojspall"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:wooUrl forKey:@"wooUrl"];

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myData.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    if (plist == nil) plist = [NSMutableArray array];
    [plist addObject:nameDictionary];

    [plist writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    [plist insertObject:nameDictionary atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Sorry can't understand what you are trying to ask. Can you please rephrase your question.

Comment: Which simply means that myData.plist not write duplicate data

Comment: So you want to load the array, plist, and insert nameDictionary into it only if there's not already a dictionary in the list that represents the same object? If so, is there a particular key field or anything else that would make spotting duplicates slightly easier?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question:

Make the plist a dictionary, not an array then read the existing plist into a `NSMutableDictionary`, add the new/updated values, write it out.  Or instead of

```
[plist addObject:nameDictionary
```

use

```
[plist addEntriesFromDictionary:nameDictionary];
```

Comment: I have tried, but the error       'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a84150'

Comment: I have added to the answer to address this.  Look carefully at the error message, it say that NSArray does not have a addEntriesFromDictionary: method.

Comment: I tried your new approach, but still the same error occurs    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a5b5d0'

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your question/code.  The NSInvalidArgumentException is caused by trying to add a mutable dictionary method to an array.

Comment: What I was not the use containsObject: to check whether the data exist? If there is no duplication of data to save data.
If so, how do?

Comment: `containsObject:` will ask the array whether the dictionary you're specifying is already in the list. That means that specific dictionary. It won't be in the list yet because you just created it. I think what CocoaFu is suggesting is that you replace your list `plist` with a dictionary. In that dictionary you store your records with their primary key as the key. Use `objectForKey:` to see if there's already something in the dictionary.